# Preview form button in another view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form where user enters some information (text boxes, select box). Inside the form I have a link_to "Preview" where users can preview what they did without saving it. They can preview it in the view of another controller I already have. Any advice on how to do this would be highly appreciated. I tried with js and ajax but it didn't work. I think that the biggest problem is how to pass form params to link_to. I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2, jQuery, JavaScript. Thanks.

Here is some code. In the second controller which checks if it is a preview or not after user clicks Preview:

```
def index
  if !params[:access_token].nil?
    @p = "something"
    @m.access_token = params[:access_token]
    @m.title = params[:title]
    @m.body = params[:body]
  else
    @p = "something else"
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

View (the first one where the form is and preview button) in haml + js, index.html.haml:

```
= form_for [:controller, @m], action: action, html: { multipart: true, id: "some_id" },    method: :post, remote: true do |f|
  - @access_token = generate_access_token
  = hidden_field_tag :access_token, @access_token

  .input-prepend
    %span.add-on Title
    = f.text_field :title, id: "title"

  .input-prepend
    %span.add-on Body
    = f.text_area :body, id: "body"

  = f.submit t("save"), class: "btn btn-primary"
  = link_to "Preview", " ", id: "preview", target: "_blank", class: "btn"

:javascript
  $("#preview").click(function(e) {

    var title = $("#title").val();
    var body = $("#body").val();
    var access_token = $("#access_token").val();

    $.get('/' + "?access_token=" + access_token + "&title=" + title + "&body=" + body);
  });
```

This .get probably doesn't make sense since it has to open in a new tab and new view.

Comment: Please can you add some code or images?

Comment: Need to see the code you have already tried, You don't need AJAX, you don't have to contact the server side, since only the DOM elements' values need to displayed in the page as it is,simple JS is enough

Comment: I updated my question with the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to open the preview in a new tab/window, you can just change your last line to:

```
var url = '/' + "?access_token=" + access_token + "&title=" + title + "&body=" + body;
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

In your `click` event you'll want to `e.preventDefault()`: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/.

However, as others have noted, you don't really need to hit the server by requesting a new preview page. You might look into using something like Bootstrap's `Modal` or jQuery UI's `Dialog` to create a "popup" on the same page. The modal content would be very similar to the preview page you have set up, but with the `title` and `body` provided by e.g. `var title = $("#title").val();`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var preview= window.open('/',title,'height=500,width=500');
preview.document.write(body); //you can write html code in it, your script vars in it
```

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.write)